# split MYSQL field into array and search

Tags: php, mysql

I have field in MySQL table. The field is called 'vehicles' When I add vehicles I add them by ID not name, so the field is populated like '2:3:4:6:7:9' 2 will be a car, 7 will be a bike, etc.

What I want to do quickly and simply is when I query the table I want to see if the field vehicle contains '2' is in that field within the 2:3:4:7:9.

I have tried a lot but coming up blank?

Thanks

Comment: You should normalize your database: Add a table with vehicles and a table to link it to the existing table.

Comment: That is really time consuming surely? It must be possible to split the '1:3:5:7:8' and see if '3' exists and proceed from there?  That has to be quicker and easier, thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad for why this is really bad idea. Changing the separator to comma would make your life a bit easier (find_in_set()), but still your queries would be highly inefficient.

Comment: Doing query hacks because of bad database design is a lot more time-consuming.

Comment: Just replace comma with colon in the duplicate topic and you get a plain answer. But the good answer is to change your design.

Comment: So whats the best and most efficient way to do this then in your opinion?

Comment: The most efficient way is what @jeroen suggested in the first comment. I linked you an SO question where you can find detailed arguments against what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to locate any specific number then do like this

```
$data = "2:3:4:6:7:9";
echo "found on index : " . array_search("2", explode(":", $data));
```

Comment: You do realize that you would have to get all rows from the database to be able to do this in php?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **FIND_IN_SET** in quer query like

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',REPLACE(vehicle ,':',',')) > 0;
```

**samples**

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('1',REPLACE('2:3:4:7:9',':',',')) as a;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('2',REPLACE('2:3:4:7:9',':',',')) as a;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('7',REPLACE('2:3:4:7:9',':',',')) as a;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('8',REPLACE('2:3:4:7:9',':',',')) as a;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Nope, finds nothing : $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.0399797000000035) ) + sin( radians(53.83428999999999) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM clients HAVING distance < 30 ORDER BY distance AND FIND_IN_SET('1',REPLACE(vehicles ,':',',')) > 0; LIMIT 0 , 20;");

Comment: @zak - it work, i have add some samples